# How to pass column names into a function dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to create a simple summary function to speed up the reporting of multiple columns of data for use in a R Markdown file.

var1 is a categorical column of data, t_var is an integer representing the quarter of data, and dt is the full data.

```
summarise_data_categorical <- function(var1, t_var, dt){

  print(var1)
  print(t_var)

  #Select the columns to aggregate
  group_func <- dt %>% 
    select(one_of(t_var, var1)) %>%
    group_by(t_var,var1)

  #create simple count summary
  count_table <- group_func %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    spread(t_var, count)

  #create a frequency version of the same table...
  freq <- dt %>%
    select(t_var, var1) %>%
    group_by(t_var,var1) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    mutate(freq = round(count / sum(count),3)*100) %>%
    select(-count)

  #Present that table
  freq_table <- freq %>%
    spread(t_var, freq)

  #Create the chart to do the same thing..
  freq_chart <- freq %>%
    ggplot()+
    geom_line(mapping=aes(x=t_var, y = freq, colour=var1))

  #Compile outputs as a list
  results <- list(count_table, freq_table, freq_chart)

  #Return list
  results

}
```

Say I've got a frame:

```
fr <- data.frame(lets = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace=TRUE),
           `quarter type` = sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

If I run the function, thus:

```
summarise_data_categorical("lets", "quarter type", fr)
```

The initial output is promising:

```
[1] "lets"
[1] "quarter type"
```

(NOTE: in trying to recreate the data, for some reason I also receive the warning:

Unknown variables: `quarter type`, 
Although this doesn't appear in my original data)

The main thing is I get an error:

```
Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : unknown variable to group by : t_var
```

Having come from Python, I'm still a bit confused on how to refer to columns. Can someone explain how I can fix what I've got wrong?

Comment: Please show only a minimal function instead of the full code.  Makes it easier for others to test

Comment: @akrun, Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use the new quosures from the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released in 0.6.0)

```
summarise_data_categorical <- function(var1, t_var, dt){

  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  t_var <- enquo(t_var)
  v1 <- quo_name(var1)
  v2 <- quo_name(t_var) 

  dt %>%
    select(one_of(v1, v2)) %>%
    group_by(!!t_var, !!var1) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) 

}
summarise_data_categorical(lets, quartertype, fr)
#Source: local data frame [65 x 3]
#Groups: quartertype [?]

#   quartertype   lets count
#         <int> <fctr> <int>
#1            1      A     1
#2            1      F     2
#3            1      G     2
#4            1      H     1
#5            1      I     1
#6            1      J     4
#7            1      M     3
#8            1      N     1
#9            1      P     1
#10           1      S     5
# ... with 55 more rows
```

The `enquo` does a similar functionality as `substitute` from `base R` by taking the input arguments and convert it to `quosures`.  The `one_of` takes a string argument, so quosures can be converted to string with `quo_name`.  Inside the `group_by/summarise/mutate` etc, we can evaluate the quosure by unquote (`UQ` or `!!`)

---

The `quosures` seems to be working fine with `dplyr` though we have some difficulty in implementing the same with `tidyr` functions.  The following code should work for the full code

```
 summarise_data_categorical <- function(var1, t_var, dt){

  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  t_var <- enquo(t_var)

  v1 <- quo_name(var1)
  v2 <- quo_name(t_var) 

  Summ_func <- dt %>%
                    select(one_of(v1, v2)) %>%
                  group_by(!!t_var, !!var1) %>%
                    summarise(count = n())

   count_table <- Summ_func %>%
                  spread_(v2, "count") 

   freq <-  Summ_func %>%
                  mutate(freq = round(count / sum(count),3)*100) %>%
              select(-count)

   freq_table <- freq %>%
                    spread_(v2, "freq")

   freq_chart <- freq %>%
             ggplot()+
               geom_line(mapping=aes_string(x= v2 , y = "freq", colour= v1)) 

   results <- list(count_table, freq_table, freq_chart)
   results

    }
summarise_data_categorical(lets, quartertype, fr)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 24 × 5
#     lets   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#*  <fctr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1       A    NA    NA     1     2
#2       B     2    NA    NA     1
#3       C     1     5     1     2
#4       E     1     1    NA    NA
#5       G    NA     1     2     2
#6       H     1    NA     1     1
#7       I    NA     1     1     2
#8       J     2     1     1     1
#9       K     1     1     2     1
#10      L    NA     2    NA    NA
# ... with 14 more rows

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 24 × 5
#     lets   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#*  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       A    NA    NA   3.1   9.5
#2       B   8.7    NA    NA   4.8
#3       C   4.3  20.8   3.1   9.5
#4       E   4.3   4.2    NA    NA
#5       G    NA   4.2   6.2   9.5
#6       H   4.3    NA   3.1   4.8
#7       I    NA   4.2   3.1   9.5
#8       J   8.7   4.2   3.1   4.8
#9       K   4.3   4.2   6.2   4.8
#10      L    NA   8.3    NA    NA
## ... with 14 more rows

#[[3]]
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help, and the explanation. And swift reply. Thank you. I'm about three weeks into R, and it's still blowing my mind. :)

Comment: That's great. I'd never heard of quosures - here's a great reference for anyone else who hadn't: http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/260900_eed544dc1f504bffb4521913eb2da86e.html