# Trouble passing column to custom function because they are unknown or objects not found

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to build a function in r that groups information and passes it back with percentage and frequency.  I built a couple of lines of code that will do it once, but when I try to place it in a function it is not picking up the column.  The error message says:  'col_name' is unknown

```
defaults <- function(df,col_name){

d_table <- df %>% group_by(col_name) %>% count(bad_loan) %>% transmute(bad_loan, percent = n/sum(n))
d_table$freqency <- (df %>% group_by(col_name) %>% count(bad_loan))$n

return(d_table)

}

defaults( loan_data, grade)
```

But this code works:

```
group_by(loan_data, grade) %>% count(bad_loan) %>% transmute(bad_loan, percent = n/sum(n))
```

I tried to play with it more this morning, but now this is happening everywhere with a `%>%`
except the error message says object not found.  I feel like I'm missing something big.  I have dplyr, plyr and tidyr loaded, am I missing a package?

Comment: Hi!, you need to add {{col_name}} or !!enquo(col_name) inside the function. For more information visit: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/

Comment: Possible duplicate of many including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438001/how-to-pass-column-names-into-a-function-dplyr